# Assigning canonical form to the differential equation using characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The problem statement is to simplify it, i.e. give it a canonical form to this differential equation using the characteristics to achieve that. However, even after many hints and trials on similar problems, I am still unable to proceed further with this one.
$$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+u_{yy}+9u_x+9u_y-9u=0.$$
Here is all the additional hints that I've been given by my professor:

We need to write the characteristic equation $A dy = (B \pm \sqrt{B^2-AC}) dx$, integrate to solve it, write parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$, $y=(1\pm ...)x+\text{const}$ and \begin{cases} \lambda= y-(1+\cdots)x\\\mu=y-(1-...)x\end{cases}
Then we basically what we are left to do is to turn $u(x,y)$ into $u(\lambda(x,y), \mu(x,y))$ by calculating $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \lambda}\cdot\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mu}\cdot\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}$ and etc.

Despite being provided all the hints, I am still struggling to connect the dots between individual hints (maybe because of some persisent unidentified error in my calculations). I would appreciate if someone could provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: I have no idea how you are expected to put the equation in canonical form using the method of characteristics, which is generally used to **solve** first order PDEs. To put your problem in canonical form I would suggest following [these notes](https://faculty.uml.edu//spennell/Teaching/PDE/classification.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the link. There is a high chance the exact mathematical wording has been lost in translation, that's why I expanded the problem statement to be more clear. What I know for sure is that it is crucial to use the method of characteristics in this case to "simplify" this equation, but I am not sure what it is supposed to mean, that being the reason I am here. This problem is taken from the class topic of "Simplification of partial derivative equations (canonical form assignment) using characteristics of the differential equation."

Comment: I think I see now. From the title of the class topic, it only sounds like you are being asked to determine the canonical form of the PDE, where new coordinates are found by finding the characteristic curves of a first order PDE (see equations $(6), (7), (9), (10)$ in the link in my comment above). To actually solve the first order PDEs to get it into canonical form, normally you would use the procedure we call [the method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: You first bring the leading order of differentiation to a normal form, if that is not unique, take information from the next-lower order to reduce the degrees of freedom. Here it should be sufficient to consider $u(x,y)=v(x+y, x-y)$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Thanks for helping. Although I have a question, why are you referring to equations $(6), (7), (9), (10)$? Isn't my given equation not hyperbolic, but rather parabolic based on the notes? Additionally, I was informed to solve with characteristics, does the solution in the notes use this method?

Comment: I meant to include equation $(15)$ there too. I referred to those equations because they are the equations that you solve to find the characteristic curves in each case. You solve those equations using the method of characteristics. Yes, the solution on the notes does use the method of characteristics, it is what is used in each example to get the explicit forms of $\xi, \eta$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell So is my equation parabolic or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It is parabolic.

Comment: It is in common use to name functions after coordinate axes and v.v. Then even if the function changes per substitution the function name remains the same. After some while this can lead to misunderstandings. It is better to use different function names for different functions, however related they may be. Thus $u(x,y)=v(\lambda,\mu)=v(y+x,y-x)$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you explain where does $v(y+x,y-x)$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$
u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+u_{yy}+9u_x+9u_y-9u=\left(\left(\partial_x-\partial_y\right)^2+9\left(\partial_x+\partial_y\right)-9\right)u=\left(\left(\partial_{x-y}\right)^2+9\left(\partial_{x+y}\right)-9\right)u=0
$$
if we change variables to

$$
\cases{
\eta=x-y\\
\xi=x+y
}
$$

$$
\left(\left(\partial_{\eta}\right)^2+9\left(\partial_{\xi}\right)-9\right)u\left(\frac{\xi+\eta}{2},\frac{\xi-\eta}{2}\right)=\left(\left(2\partial_{\eta}\right)^2+9\left(2\partial_{\xi}\right)-9\right)u\left(\xi+\eta,\xi-\eta\right)=0
$$

or

$$
4u_{\eta\eta}+18u_{\xi}-9u = 0
$$